# Cannot find Enum named Type

Tags: swift

I have a structure that contains an enum:

```
public struct TemperatureUnit : Unit
{
    public enum Type
    {
        case Celsius
        case Fahrenheit
    }

    public var type:Type

    public init(type:Type)
    {
        self.type = type
    }

    public func getFormattedStringForValue(value:Int) -> String
    {
        if (self.type == .Celsius)
        {
            return "\(value) °C"
        }
        else
        {
            return "\(value)°"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use the enum somewhere else in the code, the compiler gives me an error. The problem seems related to the name used for the enum, since the error goes away when I rename it.

example with enum named as Type:

```
TemperatureUnit(type: TemperatureUnit.Type.Celsius) // Error
```

Using the intelliSense, TemperatureUnit shows a Type property, which in turn has a Type property [...] and these Type properties all having a Type property won't let me access to my actual enum types.

**The error:** *Cannot invoke initializer for type 'TemperatureUnit' with an argument list of type '(type: TemperatureUnit)'*

working example with enum named as Kind:

```
TemperatureUnit(type: TemperatureUnit.Kind.Celsius)
```

Does anyone know why an enum named Type won't work ?

**EDIT:**

Type is a reserved keywords as we can find out with the following links. (Apple doc's information is under "Keywords and Punctuation")

- Not official: https://swift.unicorn.tv/articles/reserved-words-in-swift-and-how-to-escape-them
- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID410‌​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Type` is a reserved word in Swift. If you want to use it properly, you need to use backticks on the word. So declare your enum with

```
public enum `Type` {
    *stuff*
}
```

Kind is not a reserve word so it wont throw an error. You cannot use reserved words as variable names without escaping them properly.

Comment: See [this](https://swift.unicorn.tv/articles/reserved-words-in-swift-and-how-to-escape-them) for more info!

Comment: great link ! It's a shame I couldn't find the reserved keywords in the Swift doc. Maybe I didn't look at the good place.

Comment: Yeah. Have to keep watch on those as they do sometimes change. Swift especially since it's so new. If you have any other questions let me know! Otherwise if you could accept the answer, that'd be great. :)

Comment: @Francis.Beauchamp: It *is* documented in the official Swift docs. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID410: "The following keywords are reserved and can’t be used as identifiers, unless they’re escaped with backticks ..."

Comment: Gotcha, the reserved keywords can be found under "Keywords and Punctuation".